# OpenIddict Get User Id in the token Response

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect, openiddict, aspnet-contrib

Using ASP.NET Core with OpenIddict password grant.

When calling an authentication end point, I am getting this:

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJ...",
  "expires_in": 1800
}
```

How can I include the user id in the response? I can see it in the decoded token, but my user app will not be decoding it.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I include the user id in the response?

Ideally, consider using the identity token - always a JWT by definition - returned by OpenIddict when you specify `scope=openid`.

Alternatively, you can also enable the userinfo endpoint and send a userinfo request to get back a `sub` claim containing the user identifier: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo.

If you really prefer returning the user identifier as a token response property, you have two options:

#### Using a special "public" property (in your authorization controller, where authentication tickets are created):

```
ticket.SetProperty("user_id" + OpenIddictConstants.PropertyTypes.String, user.Id);
```

Note: `OpenIddictConstants.PropertyTypes.String` is a special suffix indicating the authentication property added to the ticket can be exposed as part of the token response. Other constants are available if you prefer returning your identifier as a JSON number or a more complex JSON structure.

#### Using the events model (in Startup.cs):

```
services.AddOpenIddict()

    // Register the OpenIddict core services.
    .AddCore(options =>
    {
        // ...
    })

    // Register the OpenIddict server handler.
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        // ...

        options.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.ApplyTokenResponse>(
            notification =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(notification.Context.Error))
                {
                    var principal = notification.Context.Ticket.Principal;
                    var response = notification.Context.Response;
                    response["user_id"] = principal.FindFirst(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Subject).Value;
                }

                return Task.FromResult(OpenIddictServerEventState.Unhandled);
            });
    })

    // Register the OpenIddict validation handler.
    .AddValidation();
```

Comment: I haven't tried as given all the friction I got, I decided it is too early to upgrade to .NET Core and it worth waiting a year or so. Thank you for the response anyway.

Comment: what is the replacement for `OpenIddictServerEventState` constants in 3+ versions? I was seeking for it a couple of days but have not found any info.